# Nativescript Masonry-like feature?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, masonry

I have an app that shows images that have different sizes. I want to display it like pinterest does. Images will automatically adjust and occupy the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can set via stretch-property: have a look in docs / widgets / Image.

Sorry, my mobile connection is to slow to load for copy and paste this moment...

Comment: Please considered enhancing your answer by [edit]ing it once you got a stable connection again, e.g. by adding an example code snippet and including the URL in your actual post.

Comment: Sorry, i just want to help him. The rest of all this stackoverflow nonsens is not in my interests

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for? http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/item-layouts#using-listviewstaggeredlayout